# remove a nested key with fluentd

Tags: fluentd

I have a file having json records and want to remove some keys form json records before sending them to fluentd output. I can use 'record_transformer Filter Plugin' to remove keys but it removes only top level keys from json. How can I use nested keys.

Sample input:

```
{
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2,
    "key3": {
        "nested_key1": 1,
        "nested_key2": 1,
        "nested_key3": 1,
        "nested_key4": {
            "double_nested_key1": 1,
            "double_nested_key2": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Output sample:

```
{
    "key1": 1,
    "key2": 2,
    "key3": {
        "nested_key1": 1,
        "nested_key2": 1,
        "nested_key4": {
            "double_nested_key2": 2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

https://docs.fluentd.org/v1.0/articles/api-plugin-helper-record_accessor#syntax

```
<filter fluentd-log.**>
  @type record_transformer
  remove_keys a, $.b.c, $.b.c.d
</filter>
```

Answer (score 5):

Ever since version [1.1](https://www.fluentd.org/blog/fluentd-v1.1.0-has-been-released) there is a new syntax to delete nested:

`remove_keys $.jsonPayload.msg`

which will delete `record[jsonPayload][msg]`

Answer (score 1):

According to [this](https://github.com/repeatedly/fluent-plugin-record-modifier/issues/15), you can use something like:

```
<record>
  for_remove ${record["docker"].delete("container_id")}
</record>
remove_keys for_remove
```

for structure like:

```
      "docker": {
        "container_id": "c1853368630a300cac78890a8599c77cea23a3fe57961e4080722c74a3ba7430"
      },
```

as result you will get:

```
      "docker": {},
```

Answer (score 0):

any of response didn't work for me.
remove-keys delete all if not nested!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).